# How can I do a GUI?

Tags: ros, rqt, gui, qt, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on a project to create a GUI which would interact with a robot using ROS. It's something relatively new for me.

I have done the beginner tutorial for ROS. Then I have seen that maybe I could create a GUI with Qt so I have started a tutorial to use this framework. But I have seen that there is also the software framework rqt of ROS that could do a GUI. I don't understand if I can still do my GUI on Qt and then imported it in ROS to use it. Because I have tried to make the tutorial of rqt but I don't understant anything :/ I did not understand the plugins and how I am supposed to create a GUI with rqt reading the tutorial. Qt seems easier for me to use.

Can someone tell me if I can use Qt ? Or if not can someone help me to understand what I should do with rqt ? (or explain me the tutorial because I don't find where I should start and what to do with the tutorial of rqt).

Thank you,

Pierre.

EDIT : Actually, I have already a program using ROS which controls my robot. What I want is to create a GUI which would enable me to change graphically the parameters of the robot for example.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238095/how-can-i-do-a-gui-?/) by [Piero-31](https://answers.ros.org/users/27292/piero-31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's nothing special about ROS that would prevent you from using any other software with it. You can use Qt or any GUI software you want with it.

Or you can use rqt, if you're having trouble with a tutorial you'll need to post a question with the specific problem you're having for someone to help. Are you working from [these](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials) tutorials?

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Piero-31](https://answers.ros.org/users/27292/piero-31/) on 2016-06-27**:
Thank you
Yes I am using these tutorials. But it's not just a specific problem, I just don't understand what the tutorial makes me do. For example the first one to create a plugin, I don't understand for what it is usefull, is it to create a GUI ? What are the plugins used for ? It is not clea

**Comment by [Piero-31](https://answers.ros.org/users/27292/piero-31/) on 2016-06-27**:
But if I make my GUI on Qt, how can I make it interracting with the robot on ROS ? I supposed that I have to make some changes. Is it explained somewhere ?

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2020-08-03**:
Yes, the tutorials are often a bit cryptic and hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [ros_qml](https://github.com/bgromov/ros_qml) package. Right now the installation process is not very straight forward, but it is definitely easier to create a graphical interface in [Qt QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html), than writing a plugin for `rqt`.

Publishing a message from QML is as easy as this:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import Ros 1.0

ApplicationWindow {

  Ros {
    id: ros

    Publisher {
      id: pub1
      topic: Topic {
        name: "/my_topic"
        type: "std_msgs/Header"
      }
    }
  }

  Button {
    text: "Publish"
    onClicked: {
      var now = ros.now()
      ros.loginfo('Sample info message with user data: ' + JSON.stringify(now))

      var msg = {
        seq: 0,
        stamp: now,
        frame_id: 'test_frame',
      }

      pub1.publish(msg)
    }
  }
}
```

For more examples, please see [examples/](https://github.com/bgromov/ros_qml/tree/master/examples) folder.

---

**EDIT:**

`ros_qml` is an essential part for creating QML GUI "connected" to ROS. It is a QML plugin (module) that exposes ROS features, such as publishers and subscribers. So there is no choice between Qt Quick and `ros_qml` — you need both. Also the package sets up the proper environment for Qt Creator, such that code-completion works fine for `ros_qml`.

I believe QML is extremely good for simple GUIs and it is usually a matter of minutes to create an interface.

If you are confident with installing dependencies from source (as described in [ros_qml/README.md](https://github.com/bgromov/ros_qml/blob/master/README.md)), then I would recommend to use QML. Otherwise it might be too confusing.

The main hitch with installation is that PyQt 5.4 (Python module used by `ros_qml`) is precompiled only for Python 3, while `ros_qml` is written for Python 2.7. Therefore, PyQt has to be built from sources and linked with appropriate version of Python.

P.S. There seems to be not much interest in the package so far, so I didn't bother to simplify the installation process yet.

---

**EDIT:**

A common approach to change robot's parameters dynamically is [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) and it is usually used in combination with [rqt_reconfigure GUI](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure). The interface is quite limited, it lacks push buttons etc., but can be an alternative to full-featured GUI.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2016-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Piero-31](https://answers.ros.org/users/27292/piero-31/) on 2016-06-27**:
Thank you it seems really interesting. Do you recommend me to use this language ? Actually, I don't get where I have to write the code. On QtQuick ? or with ros_qml ? I don't know if it is that

**Comment by [Piero-31](https://answers.ros.org/users/27292/piero-31/) on 2016-06-28**:
But I have never used Python, I use C++ to code. Can we use QML with C++ ?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-06-28**:
QML is a programming language itself. You don't need to write anything neither in Python nor in C++. However, in order to use `ros_qml` package you should have PyQt 5.4 library with Python 2.7 bindings on your system. Most probably you will have to compile that library by yourself.

**Comment by [Piero-31](https://answers.ros.org/users/27292/piero-31/) on 2016-06-28**:
So I need to learn this new language ? Is there nothing that exists using C++ ?
Where do I have to put this library ?

**Comment by [Piero-31](https://answers.ros.org/users/27292/piero-31/) on 2016-06-28**:
I don't understand what you mean by " Also the package sets up the proper environment for Qt Creator, such that code-completion works fine for ros_qml." Does that mean that I can use Qtcreator (and the interface I have made) with ros_qml ?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-06-29**:
Yes, you have to learn this new language. For the options with C++, please refer to other answers. `ros_qml` provides plugin for QML engine, but to make Qt Creator to recognize it you have to tell Qt Creator plugin's location. `ros_qml` script named `qtcreator.sh` does it automagically.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2016-06-29**:
This questions is a bit out of scope for ROS Answers. Anyway, the library will be placed to appropriate location by the installation script. Please refer to PyQt5 [installation instruction](https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/wiki/Compiling-PyQt5-on-Ubuntu-12.04).

**Comment by [Piero-31](https://answers.ros.org/users/27292/piero-31/) on 2016-06-29**:
I edited my post because I think I was not clear enough. Is QML useful for what I want ? I want to add a GUI to interact with a code already made.

**Comment by [Piero-31](https://answers.ros.org/users/27292/piero-31/) on 2016-06-30**:
Yes I knew Dynamic Reconfigure, but I would like to design my own interface. It would be just cursors and buttons to set my parameters for example!